# Can one Hive database be used for multiple projects in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive, dart-frog

I am developing a full stack app service in Dart language. I am developing front-end using Flutter and back-end using dart_frog.

I'm using Hive as a database. Both Flutter and dart_frog can use Hive, which greatly increases productivity.

But I have a question here. Let's say I run multiple back-end projects. Can multiple back-end projects share the Hive database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your use case.

If you want to access the same hive box at the same time from different processes, you have to synchronize your access in some way, because only one process/thread/isolate may open a box at the same time.

But if your different projects use the same box one after another, then it's fine.
Of course you could also write your own dart database wrapper (like a local database server) to synchronize the access to your hive boxes.